# Matplotlib all points are on 0 at z

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I am stuck trying to plot a scatter of a mesh grid in matplotlib. Here is my code:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# minvalues = np.min(vertexarray, axis=0) # vertex array of a given polygon
# maxvalues = np.max(vertexarray, axis=0)

minvalues = [-4] * 3 # magic numbers for reproducible example
maxvalues = [4] * 3
detail = 10

meshgriddim = np.linspace(minvalues, maxvalues, num=detail)
sortedmgd = [[i[j] for i in meshgriddim] for j in range(3)]

pointfieldx, pointfieldy, pointfieldz = np.meshgrid(sortedmgd[0], sortedmgd[1], sortedmgd[2])

sortedpf = [(a2, b2, c2,) for a, b, c in zip(pointfieldx, pointfieldy, pointfieldz) for a1, b1, c1 in zip(a, b, c) for a2, b2, c2 in zip(a1, b1, c1)]

sortpfx, sortpfy, sortpfz = zip(*sortedpf)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim3d(minvalues[0], maxvalues[0])
ax.set_ylim3d(minvalues[1], maxvalues[1])
ax.set_zlim3d(minvalues[2], maxvalues[2])

plt.scatter(sortpfx, sortpfy, sortpfz)
plt.show()
```

This should produce an evenly spaced cube of points. However, it instead only generates the points on one plane:

[image: mesh grid bug]

The example test for scatter plots on matplotlib works just fine. I have tried several things but nothing has worked. I believe this is a matplotlib problem as when printed, `sortpfz` shows that there exists many different z layers.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used `plt.scatter()` when I should have been using `ax.scatter()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a regular grid, I recommned that you index `numpy.mgrid` directly:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy

x, y, z = numpy.mgrid[-2:3, -2:3, -1:4]
fig, ax = pyplot.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='3d'))
ax.scatter(x, y, z)
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I need variable amounts of points in the mesh. I don't understand why ``meshgrid`` isn't working, though

Comment: @octopirate you messed up the array processing by doing anything at all. Use `meshgrid`'s output directly: `ax.scatter(*np.meshgrid(*sortedmgd))`

Comment: @octopirate, also, you can get any size step you want from `mgrid` (`numpy.mgrid[-4:1:0.5, -2:3:0.5, -1:4:0.5]`)

Comment: both of these solutions didn't work, including using constant numbers (e.g ``numpy.mgrid[-2:3, -2:3, -1:4]`` and resulted in the same thing. My guess is it's a hardware issue?